# Iframe format for embedding

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, iframe, embedding

I'm trying to embed a 360 panorama tour into Adobe portfolio I brought this from visor but adobe portfolio just supports Iframe format :

```
<script src="/scripts/embed.js" data-vizorurl="https://patches.vizor.io/embed/mahmoudgfx/makarm_villa_a" ></script>
```

Could this above code to be converted into Iframe embed?

Comment: Not enough info to help you... (1) Who is Visor? Got a link to their manual or help docs for checking? (2) What has AS3 coding got to do with this? (3) Do you have an SWF file? If yes... first create an html to embed it. Secondly, in Portfolio just link to the same html file when editing iFrame code. Use the [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46455601/edit) button to show us what you've tried if still stuck...

Comment: Use **@** symbol to notify anyone commenting. If I did not think to check this question progress again, I would never know about your code update.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding...

> *"...Adobe Portfolio just supports Iframe format"*

If Portfolio accepts it, then just try making an Iframe like this :

```
<iframe src="https://patches.vizor.io/embed/mahmoudgfx/makarm_villa_a" width="800" height="600">
```

PS: A fully testable HTML code example (to confirm Iframe works naturally) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="https://patches.vizor.io/embed/mahmoudgfx/makarm_villa_a" width="800" height="600">

</body>
</html>
```